# Remove/Hide Options from select in div

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

I've two different div's (both dynamically generated) with the same content

CODE TPL:

```
{foreach from=$rozopt item=r}
<div id="optionsy{$r.optionid}">
{foreach from=$options item=q}
    <option id="{$q.optionid}" value="{$q.optionid}">
        {$q.option_name|escape}
    </option>
{/foreach}
</div>
{/foreach}
```

RESULT:

```
<div id="optionsy29216">
    <option id="29218" value="29218">
        wysyłamy w 24 godziny
    </option>
    <option id="31848" value="31848">
        1-3 dni
    </option>
</div>
<div id="optionsy29217">
    <option id="29218" value="29218">
        wysyłamy w 24 godziny
    </option>
    <option id="31848" value="31848">
        1-3 dni
    </option>
</div>
```

so as You can see i've two div's with different ids but with the same content. Now i want to remove one option, like `<option id="29218" value="29218">` but only from one, currently loaded div. This code is from x-cart, and i want to hide variants which are out of stock. /max avail is 0 /

JS CODE:

```
if (hasOwnProperty(variants[x][1], c)){
        var max_avail = variants[variantid][0][1];
        var sku = variants[variantid][0][5];
        globalSku = sku;
        rozkol = document.getElementsByClassName('rozkol')[0].id;
        id = getPOValue(c); //option id/value
        rozkolv = getPOValue1(rozkol);
         if((max_avail == 0)){  
            element = document.getElementById(id);
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
         }
    }
```

With this code i can remove option but from both divs.

Comment: You should avoid having elements with the same id (e.g. `29218` and `31848`) in the same HTML document. Also, a better option would be to use one `<div>`, and dynamically changing its ID based on stock.

Comment: Yes, i know but option ids are from sql and i don't have any influence to change this. I can dynamically change id but then other javascript functions dont work.

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: It's challenging to understand this without getting a full picture of your program. For example, what are these variables: `c`, `x`? What do the functions `hasOwnProperty`, `getPOValue` and `getPOValue1` do?

Comment: Also, how do you expect to remove only the variant that is out of stock, if you are only able to address the option by its ID (which is not unique)? This will only work if you're able to tell if either `optionsy29216` or `optionsy29217` is out of stock. Right now, I don't think you have that information.

Comment: hasOwnProperty is not important. getPoValue and getPOValue1 are getting option id by select id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use JQuery. you can achieve your goal with this line of code

```
$({parentdivid}).find({optionid}).remove();
```

div id = optionsy29217 ; option id = 29218

```
$('#optionsy29217').find('#29218').remove();
```